# Response header duplicated (Lumen)

Tags: php, http-headers, lumen

Continuation of: [Setting response headers with middleware in Lumen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30402806/setting-response-headers-with-middleware-in-lumen)

When using the following exception handler in Lumen, the `X-Powered-By` header is duplicated, even though `$replace` (the third parameter of the `header()` method) defaults to true (even setting it manually, as below, does not work).

```php
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException)
    {
        return response(view('not-found'), 404)->header('X-Powered-By', env('APP_NAME')."/".env('APP_VER'), true);
    }

    return parent::render($e);
}
```

The response header:

```
HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
Date: Sat, 23 May 2015 08:05:13 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.3
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Powered-By: AppName/1.0.0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

The only thing that works is to use `header_remove('X-Powered-By')` just before the call to `->header`. I should not have to do this, due to the `$replace` parameter being set accordingly.

Are there any better ways to prevent the duplication of the `X-Powered-By` header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get this to work with method chaining, however, if I did this:

```
header('X-Powered-By: '.env('APP_NAME')."/".env('APP_VER'));
return response(view('not-found'), 404);
```

... it worked as you desire. But please do notice there is only one argument in the header per the PHP manual:

```
void header ( string $string [, bool $replace = true [, int $http_response_code ]] )
```

> The optional replace parameter indicates whether the header should
>   replace a previous similar header, or add a second header of the same
>   type. By default it will replace, but if you pass in FALSE as the second
>   argument you can force multiple headers of the same type.
>
> Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

... meaning, it's not a "replace this with that" type of item like str_replace. If the string you type into the first argument is similar to another header item, it will replace it with whatever you've typed automatically.

Side note: I also tried setting the third argument of the response function to an array including the X-Powered-By header to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
expose_php = Off
```

in your php.ini in order to remove

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.3
```

[expose_php](http://php.net/expose-php)

Comment: I know I can do that, but why is the original header not being replaced? Surely it is being sent *before* my `header()` call? If I do it with `.htaccess`, it works.